# How can I write in really big font size using a QGIS html box?

Tags: qgis-3, html, font, qgis-print-layouts

I'm making a map that needs to combine different fonts and different types (italic, bold) in the same line.

The QGIS text box can let me style the box using more conventional cartographic properties, but I can't mix fonts and types.

Using the HTML box, I have complete control over font and types, but the size can't go beyond HTML size 7. Anything larger than 7 doesn't have any affect on the output.

```
<font size="7">my amazing text</font>
```

How can this be achieved? I need a font size equivalent to 120 pt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I set font-size in a surrounding span when font size alone didn't do the trick

```
<span style="background-color:%s; padding: 5px; font-size: %spx;">
<font face="%s" color="%s">%s</font>
</span>
```

https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/commit/75fae61da07ab5c7867287706751d476a6502851